# Removing White space: cleaning data in R Web data odd formatting in

Tags: r, whitespace, removing-whitespace

So I have some data I web scraped when I use write.csv, I'm getting huge white spaces in Excel.  Here is a sample of 2 rows from my data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(one="\r\n Something", two="\n\n\n another one"
```

Would anyone happen to know how to approach the issue of removing white space?

Comment: try `trimws` in R 3.2+ or `str_trim` in `stringr`

Answer (score 1):

You have two semi-complicated questions in here.  The first "Would anyone happen to know how to approach the issue of removing white space?" is too vague and complex for me to really help you beyond suggesting using the functions in the stringr package?  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ idk if that helps?

The second "Secondary: could anyone help aid me by showing me how to clean up my "referee.report" text? This is the column I'm most interested in. I would especially like to remove the "\r\n" among other things." is more of something to solve.

```
referee.report = structure(c("\r\n                                    \r\n                                        DOI: 10.5256/f1000research.6599.r7859\r\n                                    \r\n                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \r\n                                        I have read the revised article by Horrell and D'Orazio. They have responded appropriately to\r\n                                                                                    ... Continue reading\r\n                                                                            \r\n                                    \r\n                                        I have read the revised article by Horrell and D'Orazio. They have responded appropriately to the concerns/questions raised by all 3 reviewers. Accordingly, I recommend indexing the submitted revised article.\r\n                                        \r\n                                                                                            \r\n                                                                                                                I have read this submission. I believe that I have an appropriate level of expertise to confirm that it is of an acceptable scientific standard.                                                                                                     \r\n                                                                                    \r\n                                        Competing Interests:\r\n                                        No competing interests were disclosed.\r\n                                                                                Close\r\n                                    \r\n                                    \r\n                                        REPORT A CONCERN\r\n                                    \r\n                                ", 
                             "\r\n                                    \r\n                                        DOI: 10.5256/f1000research.6601.r7701\r\n                                    \r\n                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \r\n                                        The revision\r\n                                                                                    ... Continue reading\r\n                                                                            \r\n                                    \r\n                                        The revision is approved\r\n                                        \r\n                                                                                            \r\n                                                                                                                I have read this submission. I believe that I have an appropriate level of expertise to confirm that it is of an acceptable scientific standard.                                                                                                     \r\n                                                                                    \r\n                                        Competing Interests:\r\n                                        No competing interests were disclosed.\r\n                                                                                Close\r\n                                    \r\n                                    \r\n                                        REPORT A CONCERN\r\n                                    \r\n                                "
), .Names = c("http://f1000research.com/articles/3-288/v2", "http://f1000research.com/articles/4-34/v2"
))

cleanOutput <- function(listObject){
  listObject = sapply(listObject, str_split,"\\r\\n")
  listObject = sapply(listObject, trimws)
  listObject = paste(listObject[listObject!=""]) ##This line eliminates empty values and NAs
  return(listObject)
}

cleanOutput(referee.report)
```

Try this function?

EDIT:

This version removes the \t from the start of the lines.

Edit: 
Turns out str_trim removes the "\t" at the start of the lines.  Edit was not needed.

Comment: Thanks, what does the `str_trim` and `str_split,"\\r\\n"` do exactly?

Comment: I think that the problem is stringr 1.0.0 (since it has caused me problems before).  It turns out that for your application, you can also use trimws.  I re-edited the function.@RobertDove

Comment: it depends on your context.  have you tried the revised function?

Comment: Still having issues: see the answer I posted in and edited.

Comment: Why are you using as.character() on a list?

Comment: Update, Still having issues with paste(): see the answer I posted in and edited

Comment: "lapply" stands for "List apply" and returns a "list" as a result.  "sapply" stands for "simplified" because it simplifies the list structure.  From the help note "sapply(*, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE) is equivalent to lapply(*)."

Comment: I'm trying to write a for loop with Polka's function since lapply is giving me troubles, but I don't know how. Can you (Polka) or someone help me out? Where F1000_v2 is my dataframe, would I be close using the following? (see updated for loop answer attempt)

Answer (score 0):

**Update** so Polka's code works some what but lapply removes \'s, but since the variable in list form I'd need to convert it to a character but when I do the \'s return:

**Update** paste() to concatenate all the strings and return a single value produces the same result.

Comment: When I used gsub, it dropped the information after the first substitution and lost a lot of data.  You should check that you are not overwriting information.

Comment: You would need to give me a more concrete example of the text that has the \t ...  I developed the cleanOutput based on the text that you provide.

Comment: Hi, I rejected your edit.  The reason is because your edit breaks the function.

Comment: You can try your suggested function, but it will not work because there is a long group of spaces between the carriage return and the tab.  The tab can be cleaned from the result of cleanOutput with the line here.

Comment: Do you have stringr version 0.6.2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95208/discussion-between-polka-and-robert-dove).

Comment: You can't convert a list directly to a character with as.character().  A character is a data type - "numeric","integer", "boolean" are other data types.  A list is a data structure .  A concatenated list of characters is a string.  A string is a data structure.  When you use paste or another concatenate function on a list, you return a string of data type character. This is why you should use "paste" on the list to return a string of type character and not "as.character()".